# GUI terminal won't open

Tags: debian, terminal, i3

I am using the i3 window manager on Debian Stretch and for some reason I can't open a terminal via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or dmenu. I have tried the default terminal and gnome-terminal. I have also tried removing and reinstalling i3. TTYs still work.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the "default" terminal in i3 isn't actually a terminal it includes, it calls one of a few commonly installed terminal emulators like xterm and urxvt, including gnome-terminal:

[i3-sensible-terminal](http://build.i3wm.org/docs/i3-sensible-terminal.html)

What happens when you run i3-sensible-terminal from the command line?

Edit: you can't open ANY terminal at all via dmenu?  As long as the binary is in your $PATH it should open, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using the command sudo rm -R /etc/i3*

This caused problems with the status bar so it is not recommended